# Why ExecuteSynchronously is not the default for async await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

We know that if we uses async/await

```
await methodAsync();
var result = methodNonAsync()
// ...
```

`await methodAsync()` puts a item on the queue, so that a thread pool thread (says threadA) can execute this task.

and I would say it is optimized that threadA also execute `var result = methodNonAsync()`.

But when I check the source code https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,0fb2b4d9262599b9 of `ContinueWith` (that's how async/await works behind the scene)

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)
{
    return ContinueWith(continuationAction, TaskScheduler.Current, default, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
}
```

it uses `TaskContinuationOptions.None` not `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`,
so it means another threadB from thread pool might executes `var result = methodNonAsync(), so this is an extra context switch.

so why ExecuteSynchronously is not the default option for async await usage for performance boost?

Comment: Why do you believe that “await methodAsync() puts a item on the queue, so that a thread pool thread (says threadA) can execute this task."?

Comment: It's an even less sensible belief when you follow that up with the (correct) statement that `await` is just a fancy way of adding continuations, not a way of performing work.

Comment: No, we don't "know" that `await` puts something in a queue for the thread pool. That's what `Task.Run` does, not `await`.

Comment: Anyway, in short, [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, for starters, `await`, as a language construct, has no knowledge of any sort of continuation options or anything like that.  `await`, from the language's perspective, will call `GetAwaiter` on the awaited object, and then call `IsCompleted`, and if it's not completed, it'll call `OnCompleted`.  Thus you can make an awaitable object *do anything you want*.  You can make an awaitable object that always constructs a `new Thread` and runs the continuations there, or that throws the action away and never runs it, or uses your own custom thread pool (and not the .NET ThreadPool).  You can make a continuation that always executes all continuations synchronously on being marked as completed (however you want to allow it to even be marked as completed).

So onto what your code actually does, we can look at `Task.GetAwaiter` specifically, which returns `TaskAwaiter` (note in previous C# versions it wasn't even a public implementation, it was an internal class).  `TaskAwaiter.OnCompleted` doesn't *technically* call `Task.ContinueWith`, contrary to your statement in the question (note that the implementation details of the awaiter have changed over different versions, there might be one where it does).  It does a functionally similar thing in that it stores the delegate to be executed when the task is finished, but relevantly, none of the internal methods called *actually* store `TaskContinuationOptions`, `None` or otherwise.

`TaskAwaiter`'s implementation first needs to consider if the current synchronization context is captured, (the default behavior for tasks) which, if it needs to, prevents the execution from being run synchronously, it forces a call to the synchronization context.  Even outside that case, there are a whole bunch of other things to consider (the settings of the `TaskCompletionSource` the task comes from, the current context/scheduler, etc.) but it *is* possible for continuations to be inlined in certain situations and run synchronously as the task is marked as completed.

If the behavior of the `task` awaiter is unacceptable for your specific situation (recognizing that the awaiter's behavior is potentially configurable in some ways) you always have the last resort of wrapping the object in your own awaiter that does *whatever you want* to add the continuation.  This could possibly be implemented by adding your own extension method to `Task` that constructs your own awaiter (even if it's just calling `ContinueWith` on said task with `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`, using a custom task scheduler, etc.).

Comment: I believe for the sort of misconceptions about `await` that the OP has in the question, a much more basic answer is required...